# How can I add condition on the laravel query without may allow an SQL injection attack?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, sql-injection, eloquent

My method like this :

```
public function getTopProduct($num, $category_id, $price)
{
    if($category_id) {
        $cache_category_key = 'top-product-category-'.$category_id;
        if(cache($cache_category_key))
            return  cache($cache_category_key);

        $category_condition = 'AND d.category_id = :category_id';
        $price_condition = '';

        $param = ['category_id'=>$category_id, 'num'=>$num];
    }
    else {
        if($price)
            $price_cache = $price['min'].$price['max'];
        else
            $price_cache = '';

        $cache_price_key = 'top-product-price-'.$price_cache;
        if(cache($cache_price_key))
            return  cache($cache_price_key);

        $category_condition = '';

        if($price) {
            $price_condition = 'AND x.price >= :price_min AND x.price <= :price_max';
            $param = ['price_min'=>$price['min'], 'price_max'=>$price['max'], 'num'=>$num];
        }
        else{
            $price_condition = '';
            $param = ['num'=>$num];
        }
    }

    $query_top_product = '
        SELECT x.id, x.store_id, x.name, x.photo, x.price, x.total_sold, y.name AS store_name, y.address
        FROM products x
        JOIN stores y ON y.id = x.store_id
        WHERE x.id = (
            SELECT a.id 
            FROM products a
            JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
            JOIN users c ON c.id = b.user_id
            JOIN products_categories d ON d.product_id = a.id
            WHERE a.status = 1 AND a.stock > 0 AND a.deleted_at IS NULL AND b.status = 1 '.$category_condition.' AND a.store_id = x.store_id AND c.updated_at >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY
            ORDER BY a.created_at DESC, a.updated_at DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
        '.$price_condition.'
        LIMIT :num
    ';

    //see for protection in db raw http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries
    $products =  DB::select(DB::raw($query_top_product),$param);

    if($category_id) 
        Cache::forever('top-product-category-'.$category_id,$products); 
    else {
        if($price)
            $price_cache = $price['min'].$price['max'];
        else
            $price_cache = '';

        Cache::forever('top-product-price-'.$price_cache,$products); 
    }

    return $products;
}
```

The method above works. But when I check my project using https://insight.sensiolabs.com, there exist error like this :

> If provided by the user, the value of $category_condition may allow an
>   SQL injection attack. Avoid concatenating parameters to SQL query
>   strings, and use parameter binding instead.

Whereas I had using parameter binding

I'm still confused to solve my problem. Because from my case need code like that. I want to using laravel eloquent. But from my query, seems that's difficult

From my code above, I also use cache. So if its cache already exists, it will grab from the cache

How can I solve the error?

Comment: You could use the quote function from the pdo object. `$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();` .. `$pdo->quote($unsafeVar);`

Comment: @Raymond Nijland, I do not understand what you mean. Try to explain in more detail

Answer (score 0):

Laravel comes with Mysql Injection protection by default, you just need to use Eloquent or Query Builder, for example:

```
$users = User::select('*');

if ($request->has('only_active')) {
    $users->where('active', true);
}

if ($request->has('search')) {
    $users->where('name', 'like', '%'.$request->search.'%');
}

// a lot of more filters you can add...

return $users->get();
```

Laravel also provides [support for joins](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins) you can apply using Eloquent or Query Builder

Comment: I want to use laravel eloquent. But my query is quite complex. In addition I also use `cache` to speed up the process

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. No need to add anything special because $category_condition is part of your query and is **not provided by user**.

Laravel's Query Builder (I mean **DB class** you already used) is protected against **SQL Injection** - even for raw queries - as long as you use parameter bindings.
You may [Read documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#running-queries) for more information.

Anyway your code will be much readable if you use Laravel's standard query builder instead of raw queries.

Comment: Do you mean my code is not problematic? But why there is an error message when I check using sensiolabs?

Comment: @SuccessMan it is for user provided vars and sensiolabs suggests you use parameter bindings, which you already used. It is clearly mentioned "If provided by user" but it isn't provided by user, it is part of the query. The problem is your code is a little messy, but the code is protected against SQL Injection for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is safe, because although you interpolate PHP variables `$category_condition` and `$price_condition` into the final query, those variable do not contain any unsafe content. In all of your code paths, those variables are set to fixed strings, not any content depending on user input or other unsafe data.

So the sensiolabs check is being overly cautious. They wrote a naive attempt to find unsafe variables, and they didn't get it quite right. I don't mean to disparage their efforts — to do it right, you really need the language to support [Taint Checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taint_checking), but PHP has no support for this.

If you want to pass the sensiolabs test, I assume (though I have not tried it) that you have to write the entire query as a single string with no variables. This means repeating most of the query in each of your code paths.

```
if($category_id) {
    $cache_category_key = 'top-product-category-'.$category_id;
    if(cache($cache_category_key))
        return  cache($cache_category_key);
    $query_top_product = '
        SELECT x.id, x.store_id, x.name, x.photo, x.price, x.total_sold, y.name AS store_name, y.address
        FROM products x
        JOIN stores y ON y.id = x.store_id
        WHERE x.id = (
            SELECT a.id 
            FROM products a
            JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
            JOIN users c ON c.id = b.user_id
            JOIN products_categories d ON d.product_id = a.id
            WHERE a.status = 1 AND a.stock > 0 
              AND a.deleted_at IS NULL AND b.status = 1 
              AND d.category_id = :category_id 
              AND a.store_id = x.store_id 
              AND c.updated_at >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY
            ORDER BY a.created_at DESC, a.updated_at DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
        LIMIT :num
    ';
    $param = [
        'category_id'=>$category_id,
        'num'=>$num
    ];
}
else {
    if($price)
        $price_cache = $price['min'].$price['max'];
    else
        $price_cache = '';

    $cache_price_key = 'top-product-price-'.$price_cache;
    if(cache($cache_price_key))
        return  cache($cache_price_key);

    if($price) {
        $query_top_product = '
            SELECT x.id, x.store_id, x.name, x.photo, x.price, x.total_sold, y.name AS store_name, y.address
            FROM products x
            JOIN stores y ON y.id = x.store_id
            WHERE x.id = (
                SELECT a.id 
                FROM products a
                JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
                JOIN users c ON c.id = b.user_id
                JOIN products_categories d ON d.product_id = a.id
                WHERE a.status = 1 AND a.stock > 0 
                  AND a.deleted_at IS NULL AND b.status = 1 
                  AND a.store_id = x.store_id 
                  AND c.updated_at >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY
                ORDER BY a.created_at DESC, a.updated_at DESC
                LIMIT 1
            )
            AND x.price >= :price_min AND x.price <= :price_max
            LIMIT :num
        ';
        $param = [
            'price_min'=>$price['min'],
            'price_max'=>$price['max'],
            'num'=>$num
        ];
    }
    else{
        $query_top_product = '
            SELECT x.id, x.store_id, x.name, x.photo, x.price, x.total_sold, y.name AS store_name, y.address
            FROM products x
            JOIN stores y ON y.id = x.store_id
            WHERE x.id = (
                SELECT a.id 
                FROM products a
                JOIN stores b ON b.id = a.store_id
                JOIN users c ON c.id = b.user_id
                JOIN products_categories d ON d.product_id = a.id
                WHERE a.status = 1 AND a.stock > 0 
                  AND a.deleted_at IS NULL AND b.status = 1 
                  AND a.store_id = x.store_id 
                  AND c.updated_at >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 DAY
                ORDER BY a.created_at DESC, a.updated_at DESC
                LIMIT 1
            )
            LIMIT :num
        ';
        $param = ['num'=>$num];
    }
}
```

This might be more repetition than you want, and it makes the code less maintainable, because if you ever change the SQL query you'll have to change it in three places.

So you must decide how important it is to pass the sensiolabs check.